# Webdriver wait for driver.current.url

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following code which is working fine. But when I tried to remove the sleep from the below code I am getting the assert failure error. Can someone please suggest me how I can use `WebDriverWait` for `self.driver.current.url` i.e for validating assert.

```
ele = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[""@aria-label='Add Device Model']")))
ele.click()    
sleep(5)    
self.assertEqual(True, ("adddevicemodel" in self.driver.current_url))
```

Answer (score 1):

Java and C# has already implemented `ExpectedConditions` for url. My guess is its only a meter of time until Python catches up. In the meantime you can use your on implementation

```
class wait_url_to_contain(object):
    def __init__(self, _text):
        self.text = _text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        return self.text in driver.current_url

wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[""@aria-label='Add Device Model']")))
ele.click()
wait.until(wait_url_to_contain("adddevicemodel"))
self.assertEqual(True, ("adddevicemodel" in self.driver.current_url))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me give a try.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an issue. Basically the setup method is in another file so if I pass this the above example in my current file I am getting the error

Comment: def url_contains(driver, value):
            return value in self.driver.current_url

Comment: self is not refrenced

Comment: @Prateek_J remove the `self` inside the function, it should be `return value in driver.current_url`

Comment: value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: it's already implemented, you can check it here. 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410218/webdriver-wait-for-driver-current-url?rq=1#comment78841164_44411535) from [Gaurang Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504762/gaurang-shah), this has been implemented in [Jun 13, 2017](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/234c999fe37cb2bc85979e47f17ccfe064c7923b) and is now part of Selenium for Python.

Usage with your example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

ele = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[""@aria-label='Add Device Model']")))
ele.click()    

context.wait.until(EC.url_contains('adddevicemodel'))
```